# Two distinct Geometries interacting?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, general-relativity

This question may be coming from a bit of ignorance, so if its obvious, I apologize. (My Riemannian geometry background up to this point is only what I needed to study general relativity).

Is there a way to describe two different (or distinct) Riemannian metrics "interacting" with each other. For example, lets say I have a metric $h_{\alpha\beta}$ and a completely different one, $g_{\alpha\beta}$, and I want to put them together, almost in a patch-work manner, to describe them interacting (like I have two $S^2$ one with radius $a$ and another with radius $r$ and I am pushing them together to make them one).

I am not even sure if this question makes sense, or if it is trivial (it may very well be), but any help is appreciated. (I may just be missing some math-vocabulary).

Comment: What do you mean by interacting? The only thing I can tell is that $\lambda g + \mu h$ is also a Riemannian metric for $\lambda,\mu >0$ since the set of metrics is a cone.

Comment: @Didier I was thinking that if I have a the metric for a cylinder and a sphere, and perform surgery on a section of the sphere the same radius as the cylinder to then glue together, so that the sphere now has a cap that is a cylinder. But what does the new metric look like? Or can you even describe it?

Comment: It sounds like you want to take the connected sum of the two manifolds and use appropriate bump functions to blend from one metric to the other (imagine joining the two manifolds — or two copies of the same manifold — by a smooth tube).

Comment: @TedShifrin this sounds perfect. Do you have a good reference for a bump function, or in general what you are describing?

Comment: Any book on smooth manifolds. Read about partitions of unity.

Comment: @TedShifrin Do you have a preference for a math text on smooth manifolds (all my books on it are with physics in mind).

Comment: @Cassem02 *Introduction to smooth manifolds* by Jack Lee is a really good differential geometry book, and *Introduction to Riemannian manifolds* (also by J. Lee) is a great Riemannian geometry book. I also really like *Riemannian geometry* by S. Gallot, D. Hulin & J. Lafontaine for the Riemannian part.